# get sum of JSON array values

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs

I tried to get the sum of this JSON array values. But I don't know the right way to 
to do this.

```
var taxes = [ {"1": 11}, {"2": 33} ];

result = 44;
```

Comment: That's not JSON, that's a literal.

Comment: What exactly did you try?

Comment: Why would you have an array of objects with different keys in each?

Comment: I'd recommend you start by looking at JS's `reduce` and then provide what you've tried and what doesn't work. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.reduce()` to calculate sum like this:

```js
let taxes = [{"1":11}, {"2":33}];

let result = taxes.reduce((a, c) => a + c[Object.keys(c)], 0);

console.log(result);
```

In case your objects are having consecutive numbers as properties you can use a simpler approach like:

```js
let taxes = [{"1":11}, {"2":33}];

let result = taxes.reduce((a, c, i) => a + c[i + 1], 0);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You're assuming that the property name in each object will always be sequential integers. I'm not sure I would extrapolate that from an example of just two elements.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, you are right. But may be objects are having consecutive numbers as properties. OP should clarify this.

Comment: I generally ask for such clarification in a comment before posting an answer, or I make the assumption clear in my answer.

Comment: @Barmar I've tried to add an alternate approach which is not dependent on any condition and hopefully will work in any similar case.

Comment: Can you explain how `c[[Object.keys(c)]]` works in that example? Why double brackets?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `c[Object.keys(c)[0]]`?

Comment: Yes, `Object.keys()` returns an array. Inner brackets are used for destructuring assignment. But as there is only one key, it will work with single bracket as well

Answer (score 0):

If each object in the array only has 1 key/value pair, this will work regardless if the keys are sequential:

```
const result = taxes.reduce((a, b) => a += Object.values(b)[0], 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
var taxes = [{"1":11},{"2":33}];
const result = taxes.map(a=>Object.values(a)).reduce((a,b)=>parseInt(a)+parseInt(b))
console.log("result = "+result);
```